# Get rid of Android L automatic opacity tint when using windowTranslucentStatus = true

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-statusbar

Anyone know how to get rid of this automatic tint when you use windowTranslucentStatus = true? I already have status bar colour set to transparent but when I enable windowTranslucentStatus, it seems to override that. If I disable windowTranslucentStatus, then I get the desired status bar colour but I can no longer draw the nav drawer under the status bar. I was able to achieve what I wanted using ScrimInsetFrameLayout but that has caused other problems.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` you can draw under the status bar because it automatically set two other system UI visibility flags as explained in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS):

> **public static final int FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS**
>
> When this flag is enabled for a window, it automatically sets the
>   system UI visibility flags SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE and
>   SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN.

Since you want to only use `setStatusBarColor` you need to set manually those flags:

```
int flag = window.getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( flag | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
window.setStatusBarColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));
```